# Hacer 3 operaciones distintas con un solo boton C#

Tags: c#

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, quiero realizar el calculo de estas 3 operaciones (2 divisiones y 1 multiplicación) con un solo botón (para no tener que hacerlas por separado) pero no se la manera de como hacerlo. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double fijo = double.Parse(lblfijo.Text);
    double num3 = double.Parse(txtTC.Text); 
    double div = fijo / num3;
    txtResultado.Text = div.ToString(); 
}

private void btnCalcular2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double resul1 = double.Parse(txtResultado.Text);
    double num2 = double.Parse(txtEFF.Text);
    double mul = resul1 * num2;
    txtResultado2.Text = mul.ToString();
}

private void btnCalcular3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double operador = double.Parse(txtoperador.Text);
    double resul2 = double.Parse(txtResultado2.Text);
    double div = operador / resul2;
    txtResultado3.Text = div.ToString();
}
```

PD: Utilizo "double" por los numeros con punto decimal ya que el valor de txtEFF.Text es un porcentaje.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede mantener la funcionalidad separada en tres métodos diferentes como lo tenés en tu código original, lo único que tenés que hacer es agregar los tres event handler el evento de click de tu botón.

```
button.OnClick += new EventHandler(btnCalcular_Click);
button.OnClick += new EventHandler(btnCalcular2_Click);
button.OnClick += new EventHandler(btnCalcular3_Click);
```

Recuerda que todos los eventos que se disparan soportan tener más de un suscriptor, no solo el de click. También es importante aclarar que si alguno de tus métodos tuviera dependencias con otros, por ejemplo btnCalcular2_Click usa el resultado de btnCalcular_Click para calcular algo, no deberías sumar ambos handler por separado porque haberlos suscripto en ese orden no significa que se vayan a ejecutar de ese modo.

Comment: Hola, lo que comenta @Lautaro es correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double fijo = double.Parse(lblfijo.Text);
    double num3 = double.Parse(txtTC.Text); 
    double div = fijo / num3;
    txtResultado.Text = div.ToString(); 
    double resul1 = div;
    double num2 = double.Parse(txtEFF.Text);
    double mul = resul1 * num2;
    txtResultado2.Text = mul.ToString();
    double operador = double.Parse(txtoperador.Text);
    double resul2 = mul;
    double div = operador / resul2;
    txtResultado3.Text = div.ToString();
}
```

Juntar todos las operaciones en el boton que quieres que las hagas. Como tienes las variables double de los resultados de cada operacion, te ahorras hacer el parseo del valor que dejas en los `txtResultado` 1, 2 y 3 y ocupas las variables que ya iniciaste con los resultados.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @EduardoParra saludos! Recuerda que si la respuesta te sirvio marcarla como la correcta.

Comment: Disculpa sioesi, en la caja de texto llamado txtEFF.Text quiero que cualquier número que coloque ahi (por ejemplo 30) se convierta a decimal (.30 en este caso). ¿como podria hacer esto? este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

             private void txtEFF_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string v1 = txtEFF.Text;
            decimal v2 = Convert.ToDecimal(v1);
        }

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es dividirlo por 100 y ocupar (decimal) numero/ 100;

Comment: El numero siempre transformalo a int t luego pasalo a decinal